# Google Sheets: Logging a Cells new value on a log sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am writing a onEdit function for a ledger worksheet.
I work at a music studio, and as we grow and improve we gradually increase the cost per track to cover overhead and the new studio gear.
However, We want our previous customers per song rate to be preserved.
The best way I have found to do this is with a vlookup table searching a separate price log sheet.
But I'd like to automate the logging of new prices to avoid forgetting when the price was changed or forgetting to log it all together.

The ideal solution for me would be:
[onEdit]       If the active sheet is 'setup' and active cell is 'C6']
{Copy C6 new value to first free row in column B in the page called 'log'}.

Below is my code for adding various times automatically for artists, at the very bottom is my nonfunctioning attempt to copy the new price to "log.

I also made an extremely simple sample sheet to better illustrate my goal.

```html
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                
  var s         = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var sheetName = "Boring"; 
  var sheet1    = ss.getSheetByName("Roster");  
  var sheet2    = ss.getSheetByName("Ledger");
  var sheet3    = ss.getSheetByName("Setup");
  var sheet4    = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice");  
  var sheet5    = ss.getSheetByName("Boring");
  var Log    = ss.getSheetByName("Log");
  var r         = s.getActiveCell(); 
  var Change    = sheet3.getRange('C6');
  
  var row       = r.getRow(); 
  var time      = new Date(); 
  var sheet = s.getSheetName();
  var letter = r.getColumn() ;
  var Tracking = sheet1.getRange('E' + row.toString()).getValue();  
  var Editing = sheet1.getRange('F' + row.toString()).getValue();
  var Mixing =sheet1.getRange('G' + row.toString()).getValue();
  var Master =sheet1.getRange('H' + row.toString()).getValue();
  var date = sheet2.getRange('C' + row.toString()).isBlank();
 switch (sheet){
   case'Roster':
      switch(letter){
        case 5 :
            switch (Tracking){
              case 1 :
                 time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy"); 
                 sheet1.getRange('S' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
                 break;
              default :
                if(sheet1.getRange('S' + row.toString()).getValue() > 0 ){
                  break;
                } else{ 
                time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy"); 
                 sheet1.getRange('S' + row.toString()).setValue(time);}
                break;
              case 5 :
                 time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy"); 
                 sheet1.getRange('T' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
                 break;
              case "":
                 ss.getRange("S"+row).clearContent();
                 ss.getRange("T"+row).clearContent();
                 break;
                 }//switch tracking
           break;
       case 6:
          switch (Editing){
            case 1 : 
               time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy"); 
               sheet1.getRange('U' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
               break;
            default :
                if(sheet1.getRange('U' + row.toString()).getValue() > 0 ){
                  break;
                } else{ 
                time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy"); 
                 sheet1.getRange('U' + row.toString()).setValue(time);}
                break;
            case 4 :
               time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy"); 
               sheet1.getRange('V' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
               break;
               case "":
                 ss.getRange("U"+row).clearContent();
                 ss.getRange("V"+row).clearContent();
                 break;
               }
               break;
       case 7 :
         switch (Mixing) {
           case 1 :
              time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy"); 
              sheet1.getRange('W' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
              break;
           default :
                if(sheet1.getRange('W' + row.toString()).getValue() > 0 ){
                  break;
                } else{ 
                time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy"); 
                 sheet1.getRange('W' + row.toString()).setValue(time);}
                 break;
           case 2 :
              time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy"); 
              sheet1.getRange('X' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
              break;
           case "":
              ss.getRange("W"+row).clearContent();
              ss.getRange("X"+row).clearContent();
              break;
                 }
                 break;
       case 8 :
         switch(Master) {
           case 1 : 
              time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy"); 
              sheet1.getRange('Y' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
              break;
           case 2 :
              time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy"); 
              sheet1.getRange('Z' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
              break;
              case "":
                 ss.getRange("Y"+row).clearContent();
                 ss.getRange("Z"+row).clearContent();
                 break;
                 }
                 break;
                 }
                 break;
    
        case'Setup':
           switch (letter){
               case 'C' :
               switch (row){
                 case 6 :
              var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log"); //gets the lgo sheet
              var target = Log.getRange(Log.getLastRow() + 1, 1);// "log"
              var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
              sheet3.getRange(3, 6, 1).copyTo(target, {contentsOnly:true});
                   break;}}
       
}
}
```

Here is an extremely simplified version of my spreadsheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i192uK-a-ALim7pvL-mkty_1nh_m9aghvmrxmiiRYKs/edit?usp=sharing

Here is my actual sheet if you need to see it
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PK0-WsfdRtFooLWb1GUCHjxGoQJHFLAg4CVh8pmuEO4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @TheMaster       Sure! That would have been a good thing to do! It out puts nothing and i cant figure out why. every other line of code works exactly as i intended! however the "Price Logger" does absolutely nothing. it doesn't add anything anywhere on my sheet that i can see

Comment: You did exactly what I wanted! I can edit the rest to do what i want! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sample sheet provided, Try this script:

#### Sample Script:

```
/*@description: [onEdit] If the active sheet is 'Setup' and active cell is 'A4'] {Copy A4 new value to first free row in column B in the page called 'log'}.*/
function onEdit(e){
 var rng = e.range;
 var ss = e.source;
 if(rng.getA1Notation()==='A4' && rng.getSheet().getName()=='Setup'){
    ss.getSheetByName('log').appendRow([new Date(),e.value])
 }
}
```

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)